# Submit form with jQuery (json encoded, ajax, parse original url/method)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, forms

I found a lot of questions about submitting forms without json and submitting forms statically specifying the url and method in the javascript code.

But all I am really looking for is a way to make all my forms send an ajax request in the exact way the form specified it in the first place with the only difference being that I want the data to be json encoded.

For instance a form like this

```
<form role="form" action="api/login" method="POST">
  <input name="email" value="my@email.com" type="text"/>
  <input name="password" value="mypassword" type="text"/>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

should automatically generate an ajax request like this when submitted:

```
POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json

{
    "email": "my@email.com",
    "password": "mypassword"
}
```

without me having to specify the method or url in the javascript code again.

And I don't want to write new code for every form I write. I'd simply like to have one snippet that automatically applies the above mentioned to any form.

Comment: So bind to the submit, read the action, serialize the form fields into JSON, make the Ajax call.

Comment: And make sure to return false in the submit handler, to prevent original form submission ;)

Comment: @epascarello Yes, that sounds about right. But it should bind to any submit that is located inside of a form and it should use the original method+url of the parent form.

Comment: `$("form").on("submit", function(){ alert(this.action); });` Now figure out the rest...

Comment: you are looking pure js generic script or any framework based ?

Comment: @IndraUprade jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try something like this

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: getObject($form.serializeArray()),
        success: function (response) {
            //Success Handler
        }
    });
    return false;
});

function getObject(data) {
    var paramObj = {};
    $.each(data, function(_, kv) {
        if (paramObj.hasOwnProperty(kv.name)) {
            paramObj[kv.name] = $.makeArray(paramObj[kv.name]);
            paramObj[kv.name].push(kv.value);
        }
        else {
            paramObj[kv.name] = kv.value;
        }
     });
     return paramObj;
}
```

Comment: if you wanna perform ajax submit, you will need to return false to suppress the standard submit.

Comment: Thanks @Ji_in_coding. Added return false.

Comment: Are e.preventDefault(); and return false; both necessary?

Comment: Yes @Forivin . If we didn't give preventDefault the form will submit in general way

Comment: What is serializeObject()? It doesn't seem to exist. (also, the semicolon should probably not be there)

Comment: Sorry @Forivin its just serialize updated answer .https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: $form.attr('url') doesn't exist either

Comment: It should be action.

Comment: serialize() doesn't seem to create a json string

Comment: Updated my answer. Please try that once.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $.post(
            $(this).attr('method'), 
            $('form').serialize(),
            function (data) {
                proccessmyData(data);
            }
        );
        return false;    
    });
});
```

you can write function for success call back with proccessmyData(data)

Comment: And where is the part where the original form's url and method is used?